# Is it guaranteed that the version number of an ArrayList will not overflow?

Tags: c#, arraylist

I was looking at [the implementation](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/collections/arraylist.cs#3e3f6715773d6643) of the .NET 4.5.1 `ArrayList` class, and I have noticed that it stores internally a version number to track the changes made over the list. Some of the observer classes (like the enumerator for `ArrayList`s) use this version number to check if the list was modified during that read-only operation.

That version number is an `int`, and is just a counter: every mutable operation increases the version number. So we are able to do a limited number of mutable operations on an `ArrayList`, until the version number overflows.

Integer overflow doesn't throw exceptions by default in C#, so an overflow on an `ArrayList`'s version number could occur without an immediate exception being thrown. My question is: **Is it guaranteed that the `ArrayList`'s version number will not overflow, or that if it does overflow the checking process based on version numbers will not fail?**

What comes to my mind is an application doing operations on large sets of elements which will overflow the `ArrayList`s' version numbers causing `ArrayList` versioning errors.

Comment: Note that "the .NET 4.5.1 ArrayList class" is actually "the .NET 1.0 ArrayList class"... AFAIK it hasn't changed a bit since the first version of .NET ;)

Comment: every integer could cause an overflow, as far as I know. In past .NET versions the ArrayList items were internly be treated as an object of ListItem. But in this implementation I didn´t found any use of ListItem. So maybe Microsoft changed the implementation completely and it´s not finished, yet.

Comment: @ThomasLevesque of course :P Just to be noted, the generic counterpart, `list<T>`, does exactly the same: http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/collections/generic/list.cs (And every collection, as far I can see)

Comment: I like the odds in this question but as I mention in my answer, for any real world scenario if you are trying to mutate an `ArrayList` while enumerating it, you should use a different type of programming pattern to be notified and react to collection changes, or synchronise access to the `ArrayList` and therefore prevent this issue altogether.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, it's not guaranteed. But you should not be worried about that. It's really unlikely that you'll ever suffer from that behavior.

However, you can imagine situation, when e.g. you get an enumerator, using `GetEnumerator` method, start enumerating the collection, and in the meantime change it proper number of times to make `version` counter overflow and get back to the same value again. Further enumeration should fail with *Collection changed* message, but it won't because `version` number is exactly the same as before.

btw, the same thing applies e.g. to `List<T>`.

Comment: re: *... get an enumerator ... change it proper number of times ... get back to the same value again* See my answer. The odds of *accidentally* doing this (rather than deliberately counting versions and forcing the error) are ridiculous. If you can do it, and prove it, I'll buy you dinner at a 5* restaurant of your choice in London ;)

Answer (score 2):

When it overflows (if you do > 68 ops per second every day for a year, for example) it will become -2,147,483,648. The only checks against it are for equality against the last known version, not for "is greater/less than" (afaik) so you won't get any errors.

Therefore you are only worried about it overflowing, and becoming the same number again, between checks. While possible, it is extremely improbable:

1. With 60 million adds per second, it would still take > 10 minutes to hit the same number, and then you need to have not done a check until that point to "not see" the last 4.3 billion version changes<sup>†</sup>. You are unlikely to see that happen.
2. You also need to do the check at the exact same time as the number recurs, which is also highly unlikely<sup>‡</sup>.
3. If you do see it happen then buy a lottery ticket, it must be your lucky week.

**Later edit:** I suppose the biggest point here though, is that you shouldn't really be able to do this. If you enumerate while simultaneously (synchronously or in parallel) adding and removing, you are using the wrong approach: use something like a `BlockingCollection`, events, Reactive type programming, or just lock the `ArrayList` for multi-threaded access. Therefore this is a nice theoretical question and you should never have to worry about it.

<sup>†</sup> If you are adding 60 million items per second, and taking 10 minutes to enumerate a single item in your entire arraylist and therefore spot a version change, you have other things to worry about.

<sup>‡</sup> 1 in 4,294,967,296 to be precise